# Kohana and CKFINDER. Trouble with SESSIONS

Tags: session, kohana, ckfinder

In Ckfinder config.php there are authchecking base on SESSION. In kohana main controller I set session variable. But when I check it in config.php it's always empty. 
session_start() in the beginning of the file.

What the problem? How to access to true kohana session?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple: setup cookie with kohana, check it in ckfinder.

I tried it and it is working.